# Creation of PDF from HTML(having good CSS) using iText on Google App-Engine for java

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf-generation, itext, flying-saucer

Can we use iText library for creation of PDF from HTML (having good CSS) on Google App-Engine for java. Is it necessary to use flying saucer , when we are working with 
this iText library?

Any reply please welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XMLWorker ([link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/)) which is a side project of the iText developers. Be sure to try out your HTML code before trying it on GAE, it does not support HTML that is too complex.